# vb.net get style of HTML element

Tags: html, asp.net, .net, vb.net, mshtml

I'm parsing some html to translate it into openXML xlsx.  I haven't been able to extract a style attribute.  I could brute force this with a custom parser, however, I was hoping to use mshtml as much as possible.  The source html may have some non-standard formatting.  Here are the details:

(below:  input, code, and debug output)

input string:

```
<div id="GLGV" class="GLVG1">
<div class="GLGVOuterRow" ID="GLGV_PRTS_0" style="height:20px;">
<span id="ExtID01_0000" title="Note - N0001" class="ExtID01Label">N0001</span>
<span id="Note01" class="Note01" style="display:inline-block;width:70px;">Area Name</span>
<span id="Main01" class="MainTextAll" style="display:inline-block;height:16px;width:250px;">My new area</span>
<span id="OTLID_0" class="GRPL_Hidden">8270</span>
<span id="OTLParID_0" class="GRPL_Hidden">8269</span>
<span id="PrtTyp_0" class="GRPL_Hidden">NOTE</span>
<span class="FloatClear"></span>
</div>
```

Asp.net code:

```
Public Sub TestSample()

    Dim wrkListString As String = C.AC("List")

    Dim wrkDocument As IHTMLDocument2 = New HTMLDocumentClass()
    wrkDocument.write(wrkListString)
    wrkDocument.close()

    Dim wrkAllElements As IHTMLElementCollection = wrkDocument.body.all

    Dim ws As String = ""
    Dim wrkType As String = ""
    Dim wrkStyle As String = ""
    Dim wrkId As String = ""
    Dim wrkClass As String = ""

    For Each wrkElem In wrkAllElements

        wrkType = wrkElem.GetType().ToString
        wrkId = wrkElem.id
        wrkClass = wrkElem.className
        wrkStyle = wrkElem.Style.ToString

        ws = wrkType & " , " & wrkId & " , " & wrkClass & " , " & wrkStyle & " , "

        Debug.Print(ws)
    Next

End Sub
```

Debug output:

```
mshtml.HTMLDivElementClass , GLGV , GLVG1 , System.__ComObject , 
mshtml.HTMLDivElementClass , GLGV_PRTS_0 , GLGVOuterRow , System.__ComObject , 
mshtml.HTMLSpanElementClass , ExtID01_0000 , ExtID01Label , System.__ComObject , 
mshtml.HTMLSpanElementClass , Note01 , Note01 , System.__ComObject , 
mshtml.HTMLSpanElementClass , Main01 , MainTextAll , System.__ComObject , 
mshtml.HTMLSpanElementClass , OTLID_0 , GRPL_Hidden , System.__ComObject , 
mshtml.HTMLSpanElementClass , OTLParID_0 , GRPL_Hidden , System.__ComObject , 
mshtml.HTMLSpanElementClass , PrtTyp_0 , GRPL_Hidden , System.__ComObject , 
mshtml.HTMLSpanElementClass ,  , FloatClear , System.__ComObject ,
```

I don't see the detailed style from the span id="Main01", only "System.__ComObject"

Any help with how to get the detailed inline style string would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Did the answer below work for you?

Comment: Yes, worked slick, great the see the detail.  Apologies for the delay; other threads called.  I will need that one, so very helpful, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Style property of wrkElem is an [IHTMLStyle object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa768808(v=vs.85).aspx) so you'll want to use the [cssText property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa768808(v=vs.85).aspx) of the IHTMLStyle object to retrieve the style's text.

So now to implement this information, change this:

```
wrkStyle = wrkElem.Style.ToString
```

To this:

```
wrkStyle = wrkElem.Style.Csstext
```